# Split url function in twig drupal

Tags: twig

In twig file , i have used statement like this:
    `{% set foo = url|split('/') %}` 
But when i use this code nothing happens.

```
{{foo[1]}}
```

However if i use this statement  `{{URL}}`  , i have a result.
http://example.com/my-completion/8631

I want to get "8631" using URL split
I do not know why it does not work.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the part u want to catch is always the last one, u could just use the filter `last`,

`{{ url | split('/') | last }}`

---

*Do note that the string at position 1 is indeed empty*

`{{ dump(url | split('/')) }}`

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "http:"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(11) "example.com"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "my-completion"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "8631"
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but i used code like this {{ url |render|render| split('/') | last }} than its worked well